# How does this schema define the namespace in this xml?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm not following this. Here's the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="tomas">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="pt">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="cat" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="shortVal" type="xs:short"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t:root xmlns:t="tomas">
    <pt>
        <cat>Category 1</cat>
        <shortVal>1</shortVal>
    </pt>
</t:root>
```

Which makes the correct xpath: /t:root/pt/shortVal

Why is it not /t:root/t:pt/t:shortVal

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `targetNamespace` of a schema only applies to "global" elements, i.e. those declared at the top level of the schema.  If you want the `targetNamespace` to apply to "local" elements that are nested inside a `complexType` as well, then you should set [`elementFormDefault="qualified"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#QualLocals) on the `xs:schema` element.

Comment: I'm good with it being just the outer. Thank you for the info, I could not figure that part out.

Comment: Generally, common practice is to use the same namespace for all elements, so basically XSD got the default wrong. You should normally use elementFormDefault="qualified" unless you have good reason not to.

Comment: @DavidThielen unqualified doesn't mean "just the outer" necessarily. If you have an element whose type declares local elements then those will be unqualified but if you later refactor the schema to move some of the elements to the top level so you can reuse them with `<xs:element ref="..."/>` then they change to being qualified and need the namespace prefix. Generally it's less confusing to simply use `qualified` along with an `xmlns="tomas"` default NS declaration.